# Выравнивание иконок и текста по вертикали

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Делаю верстку сайта и столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда выравниваю элементы внутри колонки, то они получаются не так, как мне нужно.

Сами элементы состоят из иконок и текста, тот же "Навигационный блок", но когда я пытаюсь выровнять все элементы по середине, .items встают как надо в самой колонке, то есть по середине, но шрифт и иконки расплываются в разные стороны. Нужно сделать как на фото, иконки ровно по полоске и текст ровно по полоске. Буду благодарен за помощь :)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.container {
        position: relative;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 195px 5fr 1fr;
        height: 100vh;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg,#0A0F20 0%,#11172E 100%);
    }

    .container .aside-left-section {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg,#0A0F20 0%,#11172E 100%);
    }

    .container .aside-left-section .logo {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 10px;
        width: 195px;
        height: 80px;
    }

    .container .aside-left-section .logo a{
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 800;
        color: #eaf2ff;
        padding-top: 20px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #eaf2ff;
    }

    .container .aside-left-section .logo .underline {
        content: '';
        width: 115px;
        height: 3px; 
        background-color: #3498db; 
        border-radius: 6px; 
    }

    .container .aside-left-section .bar {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 195px;
        height: calc(100% - 80px);
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 20px 20px;
    }

    .container .aside-left-section .bar .sidebar {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 20px;
    }

    .container .aside-left-section .bar .sidebar .item {
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #9fb1d5;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
        gap: 20px;
    }

    .container .aside-left-section .sidebar .item:hover {
        color: #eaf2ff;
    }

    .container .aside-left-section .sidebar a {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 30px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #eaf2ff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

            <aside class="aside-left-section">

                <div class="logo">

                    <button class="menu-button" id="menu-close">
                        <i class='bx bx-menu' ></i>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#">BotStats</a>
                    <div class="underline"></div>

                </div>

            <aside class="bar">
                
                <div class="sidebar">

                    <div class="item" id="active">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-newspaper"></i>
                        <a href="#">News</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-chart-simple"></i>
                        <a href="#">Statistic</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-folder"></i>
                        <a href="#">Resources</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-headset"></i>
                        <a href="#">Support</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-handshake-angle"></i>
                        <a href="#">Partner</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </aside>

            </aside>
```

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Нужно чтобы текст был выровнен по левой стороне, но я не могу понять, как это сделать. Если даже я выровняю текст и сделаю отступ через gap, то у иконок разный размер и текст будет стоять не ровно, нужно как то выровнять их по отдельности, и иконки и сам текст, а отступы между иконками и текстом сделать через margin) Но если есть вариант более легче и без лишнего дрочева, тогда буду рад выслушать

Comment: Добавьте в стили `.item i { width: 30px; }` и `.item a { width: 100%; }`

Comment: Не помогло, видосов уже кучу перерыл, ничего для себя нужного не подчеркнул. Если есть возможность, показать это в воспроизводимом виде и с иконками font awesom cnd

Answer (score 2):

```css
.my-flex-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 180px;
}

.my-flex-box {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-flex-cont">
  <div class="my-flex-box">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-house-door-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M6.5 14.5v-3.505c0-.245.25-.495.5-.495h2c.25 0 .5.25.5.5v3.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.146-.354L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293L8.354 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-6 6A.5.5 0 0 0 1.5 7.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5Z"/>
</svg></div>
  <div class="my-flex-box">Home</div>
  <div class="my-flex-box"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-newspaper" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M0 2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 1h11A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 14 2.5v10.528c0 .3-.05.654-.238.972h.738a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v9a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5H1.497A1.497 1.497 0 0 1 0 13.5v-11zM12 14c.37 0 .654-.211.853-.441.092-.106.147-.279.147-.531V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v11c0 .278.223.5.497.5H12z"/>
  <path d="M2 3h10v2H2V3zm0 3h4v3H2V6zm0 4h4v1H2v-1zm0 2h4v1H2v-1zm5-6h2v1H7V6zm3 0h2v1h-2V6zM7 8h2v1H7V8zm3 0h2v1h-2V8zm-3 2h2v1H7v-1zm3 0h2v1h-2v-1zm-3 2h2v1H7v-1zm3 0h2v1h-2v-1z"/>
</svg></div>
  <div class="my-flex-box">News</div>
  <div class="my-flex-box"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bar-chart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M1 11a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3zm5-4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v7a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H7a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V7zm5-5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2z"/>
</svg></div>
  <div class="my-flex-box">Statistic</div>
  <div class="my-flex-box"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-folder-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M9.828 3h3.982a2 2 0 0 1 1.992 2.181l-.637 7A2 2 0 0 1 13.174 14H2.825a2 2 0 0 1-1.991-1.819l-.637-7a1.99 1.99 0 0 1 .342-1.31L.5 3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3.672a2 2 0 0 1 1.414.586l.828.828A2 2 0 0 0 9.828 3zm-8.322.12C1.72 3.042 1.95 3 2.19 3h5.396l-.707-.707A1 1 0 0 0 6.172 2H2.5a1 1 0 0 0-1 .981l.006.139z"/>
</svg></div>
  <div class="my-flex-box">Resource</div>
  <div class="my-flex-box"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-headset" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 1a5 5 0 0 0-5 5v1h1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V6a6 6 0 1 1 12 0v6a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-2.5 2.5H9.366a1 1 0 0 1-.866.5h-1a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h1a1 1 0 0 1 .866.5H11.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 13 12h-1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V8a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1V6a5 5 0 0 0-5-5z"/>
</svg></div>
  <div class="my-flex-box">Support</div>
  <div class="my-flex-box">
    <svg height="16px" width="16px" version="1.1" id="_x32_" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 460 460" xml:space="preserve" fill="#000000"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <style type="text/css"> .st0{fill:#000000;} </style> <g> <path class="st0" d="M255.366,141.046c-7.4,3.583-14.732,8.548-21.533,15.357c-34.091,34.098-65.081,65.088-65.081,65.088 l0.013,0.02c-0.185,0.186-0.371,0.338-0.557,0.53c-8.824,8.831-9.174,22.909-1.025,32.146c0.323,0.371,0.668,0.736,1.025,1.086 c9.161,9.174,24.036,9.196,33.232,0l35.797-35.797c6.176,2.263,12.248,3.583,18.074,4.243c7.937,0.88,15.392,0.55,22.022-0.385 c16.162-2.29,14.47-1.623,23.844-4.704c9.353-3.068,19.862-9.354,19.862-9.354l6.362,6.355 c0.701,0.681,16.919,16.925,25.192,25.185c1.465,1.471,2.709,2.682,3.542,3.549c0.956,0.997,2.022,1.719,2.682,2.682l41.278,41.279 c11.898-13.35,25.488-33.232,23.81-56.058L320.763,129.14C320.763,129.14,285.062,126.589,255.366,141.046z"></path> <path class="st0" d="M261.115,394.362c-9.134-9.147-23.961-9.147-33.101,0l-6.794,6.794c9.119-9.132,9.112-23.926-0.021-33.066 c-9.14-9.126-23.947-9.126-33.087,0.007c9.14-9.133,9.14-23.94,0-33.087c-9.133-9.148-23.947-9.133-33.087,0 c9.14-9.133,9.14-23.947,0-33.095c-9.134-9.132-23.947-9.132-33.088,0.014l-20.46,20.453c-9.14,9.147-9.14,23.947,0,33.094 c9.133,9.134,23.941,9.134,33.08,0c-9.14,9.134-9.14,23.947,0,33.087c9.147,9.133,23.954,9.133,33.094,0 c-9.14,9.133-9.14,23.941,0,33.088c9.14,9.133,23.947,9.133,33.088,0l6.802-6.809c-9.119,9.147-9.113,23.94,0.02,33.081 c9.14,9.132,23.947,9.132,33.088,0l20.467-20.468C270.248,418.302,270.248,403.495,261.115,394.362z"></path> <path class="st0" d="M507.987,178.28L387.543,57.822c-5.351-5.337-14.002-5.337-19.339,0l-38.631,38.63 c-5.337,5.337-5.337,13.989,0,19.333l120.458,120.451c5.33,5.35,13.996,5.35,19.326,0l38.63-38.638 C513.338,192.276,513.338,183.624,507.987,178.28z M473.655,204.992c-5.75,5.736-15.048,5.736-20.777,0 c-5.735-5.743-5.735-15.041,0-20.777c5.729-5.736,15.027-5.736,20.777,0C479.391,189.951,479.384,199.249,473.655,204.992z"></path> <path class="st0" d="M182.417,99.864l-38.624-38.63c-5.336-5.337-13.995-5.337-19.332,0L4.003,181.691 c-5.337,5.323-5.337,13.989,0,19.319l38.631,38.644c5.33,5.331,14.002,5.331,19.325,0l120.458-120.458 C187.761,113.859,187.761,105.207,182.417,99.864z M59.118,208.403c-5.736,5.729-15.04,5.729-20.777,0 c-5.735-5.742-5.735-15.041,0-20.777c5.736-5.735,15.041-5.735,20.777,0C64.854,193.362,64.854,202.66,59.118,208.403z"></path> <path class="st0" d="M397.528,312.809l-7.468-7.482l-72.509-72.509l-4.883,2.166l-5.316,1.919l-0.384,0.117 c-0.936,0.296-9.684,2.971-26.932,5.412c-9.12,1.273-18.156,1.431-26.904,0.434c-3.459-0.385-6.898-0.95-10.296-1.692 l-27.757,27.744c-16.678,16.678-43.836,16.678-60.514,0c-0.585-0.591-1.149-1.19-1.671-1.781l-0.179-0.2 c-10.529-11.939-13.204-28.28-8.252-42.461l10.673-16.609l-0.02-0.02l65.081-65.074c2.647-2.641,5.426-5.103,8.314-7.428 c-20.281-3.982-37.296-2.806-37.296-2.806L88.093,235.679c-1.389,18.988,11.651,39.799,20.928,51.952 c16.692-15.963,43.239-15.756,59.641,0.654c6.107,6.1,9.952,13.617,11.574,21.498c7.895,1.637,15.406,5.475,21.513,11.582 c6.107,6.114,9.952,13.631,11.575,21.519c7.888,1.623,15.412,5.46,21.513,11.568c4.078,4.078,7.152,8.783,9.222,13.817 c11.1-0.137,22.242,4.016,30.688,12.455c16.65,16.636,16.643,43.733,0,60.363l-6.809,6.822l3.411,3.412 c9.148,9.147,23.954,9.147,33.095,0c9.14-9.134,9.14-23.947,0-33.088l6.808,6.83c9.147,9.133,23.947,9.133,33.087,0 c9.14-9.147,9.147-23.954,0-33.101c9.147,9.147,23.947,9.147,33.087,0c9.134-9.126,9.154-23.94,0-33.088 c9.154,9.148,23.954,9.148,33.088,0c9.147-9.132,9.147-23.947,0-33.08L397.528,312.809z"></path> </g> </g></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="my-flex-box">Partner</div>
</div>
```

Вот так это можно реализовать, если я Вас правильно поняла, и если Вы рассматриваете flex.